# How to get the names of all tables present in a database in Android SQL lite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I cant find a way to get/dump table names in a text view from a database in android.  I know about:querying

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sqlite_master
```

The above statement results a cursor pointing the metadata about all databases/view/tables. But how can I fetch the names of all the tables I created, in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the info in an array (or any structure which you can iterate through strings), you can make a method like:

```
public String[] getDBNames(){
    String[] result;
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master "); 
        sb.append("WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' ");
        sb.append("UNION ALL ");
        sb.append("SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master "); 
        sb.append("WHERE type IN ('table','view') ");
        sb.append("ORDER BY 1");

        Cursor c = _db.rawQuery(sb.toString(), null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        result = new String[c.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            result[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            i++;
        }
        c.close();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("OOPS", e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is good code, but skips the first entry and includes the android_metadata table in the result.  To fix this, switch the `while (c.moveToNext())` loop to a `do . . . while` loop, and then made the SQL `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' AND name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata' ORDER BY name`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are asking for the SQL or Android rendering code, but according to the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7), this SQL should work to give you the names:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: Im sorry, but by querying it in android, it would return as a cursor ! How can i then get/dump table names queried as above in Android's TextView !

Comment: 'tbl_name' rather than 'name' looks more likely to me from a SQLite DB I'm currently looking at.

Comment: the above query will only return the tables I created in database, and not the tables specific to androids own business i.e. prefixed as 'sqllite_' right ?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're just trying to poke around a database, you can just load it up in sqlite3 in adb shell and run ".tables":

```
cd data/data/com.whatever.appname/databases
sqlite3 DBNAME
.tables
```